# Remove a Git error message

Tags: macos, bash, git

I am writing a small git terminal script. everything is finished but i have a error. When theres no git dir, i can't seem to pipe the error to dev null. 
`git status --porcelain --branch | grep -Eo '\[[a][hea]*[d].[1-9]' | sed 's/\[//' | awk '{print $(NF $0)}'2>/dev/null`
Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `2>/dev/null` is applied to `awk`, not `git`.  You need to put it after the `git` command, or wrap the whole pipeline in curly braces and redirect stderr after the close brace to get them all.